# Is this routine good?

Tags: training

https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/kb/recommended_routine

Somehow my body doesn't supercompensate.
And why does the line at the end of the supercompensation goes back to the baseline? Shouldn't the supercompensation stay for few days or at least stay horizontally?

[image: tests]

[image: test]

My body reacts more like this. No supercompensation. Don't forget to read the routine in the link at the top. It tells you how often i rest. I mean you can't tell me my body doesn't have enough rest with 3 full body workouts per week as a full bloody beginner who can't do 10 push ups in 1 set.

Cause i rarely hit supercompensation, meaning i am not stronger in the next workout, so either my workouts are in the recovery mode or after the superc. mode

Thank you, if you answer every question.

Comment: Are you saying your progress is actively going down?  As in your capable of doing less?

Comment: I don't think this is a good question, but, don't confuse that with the idea that I don't want to help you. The answer to "Is this routine good?" is "It depends". Depends on your goals. The body of your question reads more like you're still not seeing progress but that could be completely independent of the routine. I would rather see you re-work this question into: "I am still not seeing progress following a callisthenics routine" and include what your last three weeks of training, diet, and sleep have looked like. Also, include what changes you've adopted since your last question.

Comment: @C.Lange goal is hypertrophy. diet: https://i.imgur.com/WcxtPIe.png and https://i.imgur.com/0bTemDs.png
sleep 8h or more.

Comment: @C.Lange training.  first was 18 sets per muscle per week for MONTHS aka the bwf rr. then i wanted to implemented this volume guide of israetel.  that's why i choose going straight up to 30 sets, cause training all the time with 18 sets, i must have build up enough volume to jump directly to 30 sets. then i did one week with 30 sets per week, then i did a week with 36 sets per week. and now i wanted to do 18 sets. but i cant add reps. i still can do the same amount of reps like the last 2-3 weeks. i thought after 2 weeks of so much volume. like more than MRV, that i might add 1 rep in all sets

Comment: 16-20 sets for a large muscle group, and 9-12 sets for smaller muscle groups is usually the range for most people who arent advanced weightlifter/bodybuilders. I think you're overtraining. And thanks for posting your diet, but are you gaining weight? gaining muscle mass as a beginner is important to getting strength and size, so you want to make sure you're gaining a lb or so each week. Also for hypertrophy, you should not use strength as an accurate way of testing your progress, because the goal is size, not strength. sometimes its both, but if you want to get stronger,  work on strength

Comment: @AceCabbie no u dont need kcal surplus for gaiing streingth. and i didnt even gain strength. totally non responder.

Comment: @Stjema You said your goal in the comments was hypertrophy which would involve a calorie surplus. Without getting into the science of gaining strength, you need to eat a surplus if hypertrophy is your goal.

Answer (score 3):

allow me to have some input on this.

I read all your threads and I can understand your frustration. Obviously, training for several months with no results, be it appearance-wise or in the exercises themselves, can be upsetting. Your routine is good exercise-wise. You're doing a full-body routine with the main compound exercises. However, your body doesn't react much (past a certain point), because you lack stimulation. You're essentially doing the same thing over and over again, which diverges to a plateau.

There is a simple way to apply progressive overload: weights

I used to struggle a lot, especially with pull-ups. I could do 3 with the correct form but past that, it was pretty much impossible to add a single one and no amount of sessions would increase them. Therefore, what I did was take a backpack, put a 250ml bottle of water inside it and wear it on the front side. Every first set of the exercise would be done with weights and the last two without (sometimes I replaced them with negatives). Week after week, I added another small bottle. Grams became kilos, bottles became plates, the backpack became a belt and the weights increased. I always managed to do at least 3 reps (my initial max without weights) because of the small increments of weight. You barely feel a difference carrying a 250ml bottle and thus your body naturally adapts to it. I was never risking any injury in the process

The first time I performed my first ever starting set of bodyweight pull-ups, I easily did 10-12 reps, not even to failure. I managed to keep +- the same rep range on the other sets. You can overwrite this concept on other exercises like dips, push-ups, etc. Look, man, you need to understand why you do those exercises. You need to set up a systematic structure that FORCES you to progress. This isn't something your body decides, this is something you decide and no amount of blaming it on that non-responder nonsense will help you.

PS: Add ab exercises. The 2 important ones are planks and leg raises. In contrast, include lower back extensions as well.

Comment: Good answer. I always think of bodyweight exercises like pull ups or push ups more as things you can do once you're strong enough or have the athleticism to do. Also abs like you said, are very important for a pushup

Comment: already tried adding weights. no progress. u dont need weights btw. just do negative pull ups after 3 full pull ups. u didnt know that? its great progression and very easy.

Comment: @Stjema yes I did know that, but negative pull ups are different from push ups which is what you are talking about in your post, you cant do a negative pushup. and doing extra exercises like inverted rows does more wonders than negatives.  BTW based off your argumentative comments it seems like you know more than a lot of us here, so why are we helping you with your question? If you know how to make great easy progress, why did you make a post asking how to make progress?

Comment: @AceCabbie why would exercise matter? its all same. im not progressing in any of em. even if going with easy small progression steps like increasing 1sec in negative pull ups.  this is like adding 1kg to full pull up. perhaps even less lol. ur helping me cause i dont know anymore. im sorry if i sound like smartass. dont do this onpupose.  yes i know how to make easy progress... the routine tells u that. its very easy. but whatever i do it doesnt work for mw.

Comment: @AceCabbie i started scapular pulls and push ups, and ill only progress with adding weigh to my backpack. nothing else. ill see if my progress is better than adding 1 sec per exercise per session or adding 1 rep. or doing negatives only etc. negatives are very easy progression form.